# Validating XHTML elements with XML children

Tags: xml, validation, xhtml, xsd, modularization

G'day guys,
I've tried reading the XML Modularization recommendation which promises to allow custom XHTML extensions but can't make heads nor tails from it. I need an XML document containing a mix of XHTML and user-defined XML elements to validate and having trouble doing so. Unfortunately I'm using an XSD and not a DTD, a la XSL which validates XSL elements as children of XHTML elements. Here's a short sample of what I'd like to validate:

```
<html><head><title><my:element name="titledata" /></title></head><body /></html>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of completeness, here is a link to the modularization spec which will allow you to extend the XHTML shema - http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/